# Loading GTK2 in PHP fails

Tags: php, gtk2

I already did the following:

```
Installed PHP 5.3.3

Installed GTK 2.0.1

Installed the latest version of php-gtk from svn

All dependencies are resolved and installed.
```

I edited `php.ini` to load the GTk library in extension lib of PHP, as `extension=php_gtk2.so` and saved it.

If I check with `php -m` I'm finding one error like `Unable to Load Dynamic Library ../../php_gtk2.so` I'm assuming it may be because `php_gtk2.so` is a static library.

Then how can I load it.? Any idea where I made mistake?

I'm running on `CentOS 6.0 Server`,`PHP 5.3.3`,`GTK 2.0.1`

```
edit:
```

The exact problem is given below:

```
    [root@srv-vg phpapps]# php -m
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/modules/php_gtk2.so' - 
/usr/lib/php/modules/php_gtk2.so: 
undefined symbol: php_cairo_get_context_ce in Unknown on line 0
    [PHP Modules]
    apc
    bz2
    calendar
    Core
    ctype
    curl
    date
    dom
    ereg
    exif
    fileinfo
    filter
    ftp
    gd
    gettext
    gmp
    hash
    iconv
    json
    ldap
    libxml
    memcache
    mysql
    mysqli
    odbc
    openssl
    pcntl
    pcre
    PDO
    pdo_mysql
    PDO_ODBC
    pdo_pgsql
    pdo_sqlite
    pgsql
    Phar
    readline
    Reflection
    session
    shmop
    SimpleXML
    soap
    sockets
    SPL
    sqlite3
    standard
    tokenizer
    wddx
    xml
    xmlreader
    xmlrpc
    xmlwriter
    xsl
    zip
    zlib

    [Zend Modules]
```

As hakre said, i tried loading `cairo extension` by adding the `cairo.ini` file. But now its also showing some error like this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/cairo.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/cairo.so: undefined symbol: cairo_ce_cairosubsurface in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/php_gtk2.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/php_gtk2.so: undefined symbol: php_cairo_get_context_ce in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
```

edit2:

When i was installing `cairo`, there was a bug in `cairo_surface.c` and i cleared it as some one in the forums told to do how. I could install `cairo` successfully. But now, what about this!!

Comment: Is GD enabled in your PHP instalation?

Comment: are you sure your `php_gtk2.so` is in `extension` dir?

Comment: in the /ext/php.d folder i have gd.ini and php_gtk2.ini, and in the /usr/lib/php i have both the .so modules also.

There was some mentioning of this error in google, but none provided a solution.  :(

Comment: edited to add the problem result and because of this, i cannot use the class  like Gtk...

Comment: I remember trying that too and took me a few days which afterwards lost all interest into it. But i had to compile LIB GTK by myself at a special place cause there were no package avail

Answer (score 1):

So you installed from SVN. But something with the compiled binary has a problem to find the symbol `php_cairo_get_context_ce`.

Your module list shows that you do not have the [cairo extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/cairo) installed.

Install it and load it *before* php-gtk.

Comment: It's not part of your module list.

Comment: You should update the output of `php -m` then in your question.

Comment: cairo_ce_cairosubsurface  is a symbol defined as a structure elemnt in one zend-headerfile. I have that header file in right place. But still its not wrking.

Comment: @Krishnanunni: Sorry, now I've seen it, it fails to load, too.

Comment: So cairo is not installed properly. Have you installed it as well? It must be in a version compatible to the GTK module and naturally compatible with the cairo libs on your system.

Comment: I installed cairo with pecl first, it was throwing the same error @ installation, so downloaded source, cleard bug and installed.

Comment: There is a mismatch between the header definitions and the binary library in your system. Please check which cairo version you have installed with your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in ubuntu. What I have done to fix it was

1. Changed the permission of the files **php_gtk2.so**, **cairo.so** in the directory **/usr/lib/php5/20121212** to **644** . Earlier it was **777**. The last number in the path may be different for other systems which I don't know.
2. Updated the file `sudo gedit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` Added the entry for these two modules in the section named **Dynamic Extensions**

   **`extension= /usr/lib/php5/20121212/cairo.so
   extension= /usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_gtk2.so`**

Please note the order, **cairo.so** must be the first one. Earlier **php_gtk2.so** was the first one which caused the error I believe.

3. Finally managed to run the demos from the directory **php-gtk-src** from terminal using the command `$ php demos/phpgtk2-demo.php`

Hope it helps :)